# Real Analysis II --- power series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, power-series

If f(x)= $\int_0^x \frac {ln(1+u)}{u}$ du, find a series for f(x) and calculate the approximate value of f(0.1). Use the error upper bound for approximating an alternating series to give an upper bound for the error in your approximation. It is up to you to decide how precise your estimate will be.

Attempt:
Given ln(1+x)=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $(-1)^{n+1} \frac {u^n}{n}$, we have $\frac{(-x)^{n-1}}{n}$=$\frac {ln(1+u)}{u}$. So f(x)=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $(-1)^{n-1} \frac {u^n}{n^2}$ and then I just plug u=.1 and add terms together to n= a large enough number I deem precise enough?

Comment: The series for the log is well-known and the resulting integral produces a nice series, accurate enough for the value you intend to plug in.  Are you sure you have it correct?  What does your term-by-term integration look like?

Comment: @RonGordon, see my edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ron Gordon commented, (I typed this before your edit), start with $$\log(1+u)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^n}n$$ so, $$\frac {ln(1+u)}{u}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^{n-1}}n$$ $$\int\frac {ln(1+u)}{u}du=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^{n}}{n^2}$$ $$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac {ln(1+u)}{u}du=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n^2}$$ $$f(\frac 1 {10})=\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{400}+\frac{1}{9000}-\frac{1}{160000}+\frac{1}{2500000}+\cdots$$ Just think about Lagrange remainder for a Taylor  series (in your case, what is interesting is that the series alternates, so $\cdots$).

**Edit**

As said in a comment, we can explicitly know the number of terms $ k$ to be added for a given accuracy $\epsilon$. Using Lagrange remainder, we then need to solve $$\frac{x^k}{n^2} \leq \epsilon $$ Any equation which can write $A+B x+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has an explicit solution in terms of Lambert function.

In the case of the current problem the solution is then given by $$n \geq-\frac{2}{\log (x)}W\left(\frac{\log ^2(x) \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon }{\log ^2(x)}}}{2 \epsilon }\right)=-\frac{2}{\log (x)}W\left(\frac{|\log (x)|}{2 \sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)$$ What is nice is that there are very good approximation of Lambert function $W(z)$. The first terms are given by $$W(z)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(z)$, $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

For illustration purposes, let us take $x=\frac 1{10}$ and $\epsilon=10^{-6}$; these make the argument of Lambert function $z=500 \log (10)$ so the approximation gives $W(500 \log (10))\approx 5.37193$ (the exact value being $\approx 5.36816$) and, so, $n \geq 4.66272$. So, five terms are required.

Let us check (easy, since these are the terms I wrote). Using five terms, we get $$f(\frac 1 {10})=\frac{17568947}{180000000}\approx 0.09760526111$$ while the exact value of the integral would be $$\int_0^{\frac 1 {10}} \frac {ln(1+u)}{u}du=-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{10}\right)\approx 0.09760523523$$

**Please, have a detailed look at Ron Gordon's comment**

Comment: Thanks! It seems that your answer, if not same, is similar to my recent edit ("attempt")?

Comment: I totally agree with you. As I wrote, what I typed was before your edited your post. By the way, you could be interested that there is a closed form of $k$ such that $\frac{x^k}{k^2} <\epsilon$. I did not add it to my answer because the solution involves Lambert function (and I do not know if you already heard about it).

Comment: Would you like to add the part that involves Lambert function in addition to the current solution? (Add a second solution in your answer and keep the current solution) It would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I think the Lambert function is overkill.  This is a simple series approximation to an integral and is just a trial and error thing.  The question is, at what $n$ is $(0.1)^n/n^2 \lt $ absolute tolerance, say, $1.0 \cdot 10^{-6}$?  Clearly $n=5$ works - and I just eyeballed that.  So, even if the Lambert function stuff is right, it has no place here.

Comment: @RonGordon. I totally agree with you. In a comment, I was mentioning that (because my passion for Lambert function) and the OP asked me to add that part. I was mentioning the fact that the series was alternating and I let a few dots to the OP.